# indirect bash command execution not working as expected with coproc

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution, coproc

I'm quite new to linux shell scripting and have a question:

1.) why does the command

`test1="leafpad" && coproc exec "$test1"`

work in bash (commandline, GNU bash 4.4.12 on a debian derivate linux), but the command

`test1="coproc" && exec "$test1" leafpad`

does not? Error messages:
bash: exec: coproc: Not found.

whereas
`coproc leafpad`
does work as expected.

How this command must be correct quouted to make it work? I've tried already

`` test1=`coproc` && exec "$test1" leafpad ``

`test1='coproc' && exec "$test1" leafpad`

`test1="'coproc'" && exec "$test1" leafpad`

`` test1=`coproc` && exec '$test1' leafpad ``

`` test1=`coproc` && exec `$test1` leafpad ``

`test1="coproc" && exec $test1 leafpad`

`` test1=`coproc` && exec $test1 leafpad ``

and some more variations, but none of them works.

2.) This was the test on commandline only. But what I rather need is to do this within a script: So I'm sure there are to be done some additional quotations or masquerading of special characters.

Background:
I have to execute a command, containing many arguments, some of them replaced by variables. Think of something like yad with all its possible arguments in a couple of lines, but let's create an easier example:

```
my_codeset="437"
my_line="20"
my_filename="somthing.txt"
if [ $value == 0 ]; then my_tabwidth='--tab-width=10'; else my_tabwidth=""; fi   # set tabs or not

leafpad --codeset="$my_codeset" "$my_tabwidth" --jump="$my_line" "$my_filename"
```

wherein the variables given are subject of change, as a function of user interaction before.

Now this complete command (which is about 6 lines of code in original), needs to be executed in two variants:
one time headed by coproc, and another time not, as a function of an conditional branch.

so what I want is:

```
if [ $something == 1 ]; then copr_this="coproc"; else copr_this=""; fi

exec '$copr_this' <mycommand, with all its quoted arguments>
```

instead of

```
if [ something == 0]; then
          lengthy command here
else
          coproc lengthy command here, exactly repeated.
fi
```

I tried to manage it the other way around already, which was to put the complete lengthy command in a variable, and execute it in an conditional branch:

```
my_command=`lengthy command with some arguments $arg1 $arg2 ...`

if...
      exec "$my_command"
else
      coproc exec "$my_command"
fi
```

which stopped with error message "not found" also. Different ways of quoting didn't solve it, but produced different error messages only. I didn't manage to find out the correct quoting for this task. How shold this qouting read correctly?

For sure I could repeat the 6 lines of command in the code, but I'm quite sure this could be done more convenient.

As stated in the beginning: The indirect command execution works on commandline (and within script also), **as long as coproc isn't involved**. I cant't get it to work with coproc.

Any help and hints appreciated.

---

Update after first answer from @Socowi:

Thank you for your comprehensive and quick answer, Socowi. You are obviously right about `coproc` not beeing a command. So I understand now why my attempts had to fail. The `exec` command was added only during my experiments. I had started without this, but after having no success I thought it could help. It was an act of desperation merely. The backward quotes in the line `` my_command=`lengthy command with some arguments $arg1 $arg2 ...` `` were a typo, there should have been normal quotes, as you pointed out, since I intended to execute the command within the `if` of course. I'll probably head for the way you directed me to, using `function {...}` within script. But having experimented on this question in the meantime, I came to an astonishing solution: Astonishing for me, because of the difference between `coproc` not beeing a command and `leafpad` with its binary beeing a command. So it should be clear that `test1='coproc' && test2='leafpad' && "$test1 $test2"` will fail with error message `bash: coproc leafpad: command not found.`, which is true. But now: why would `test1='coproc' && test2='leafpad' && /bin/bash -c "$test1 $test2"` do the job, starting leafpad, allowing to enter further commands in bash parallel, just as if I had entered `leafpad &` only? But this time **executing both, the builtin (or keyword?) and the command, from a variable**, which was refused when trying to enter it directly in the first bash instance. What is true for the first instance of bash should be true for the second also, or do I have a false perspective? Why does it work this way? Does the `-c` option do anything else than to execute the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting is **not** the problem here. There are two other problems:

### Order of `exec` and `coproc` and builtins vs. binaries

`test1="leafpad" && coproc exec "$test1"` is the same as `coproc exec leafpad`.
`test1="coproc" && exec "$test1" leafpad` is the same as `exec coproc leafpad`.

The order makes a difference: `coproc exec` vs. `exec coproc`. The latter does not work because `exec` replaces the current shell with the specified program. However, `coproc` is a builtin command. There is no `coproc` binary on your system. You can run it only from inside `bash`. Therfore `exec` fails.

### Command Substitution vs. Strings

In your script ...

```
my_command=`lengthy command`
if ...; then
      exec "$my_command"
else
      coproc exec "$my_command"
fi
```

... you did not store `lengthy command` inside the variable, but you ran that command and stored its output (`` v=`cmd` ``  is the same as `v=$(cmd)`) before the `if`. Then inside the if, you tried to execute the output of the command as another command.

To store the command as a string and execute it later you could use `my_command="lengthy command"; $my_command` (note the intentionally missing quotes). However, bash offers far better ways to store commands. Instead of strings use arrays or functions. Here we use a function:

```
my_command() {
  exec lengthy command
}

if ...; then
   coproc my_command
else
   my_command
fi
```

### `coproc exec`?

That being said, I really wonder about the combination of `coproc` and `exec`. To me it seems `coproc exec cmd` ignores the `exec` part and is the same as `coproc cmd`. If `exec` acted normally here, the current shell would be replaced, you would loose the `COPROC` array and therefore wouldn't need the `coproc`. Either way, using both at the same time seems strange. Are you really sure you need that `exec` there? If so, I'd be happy to hear the reasons.

Comment: I haven't tested much, but `coproc exec something` seems to be equivalent to just `coproc something` -- the `exec` happens in a subshell that (given a simple command) was going to exec the command anyway. But there's another complication: `coproc` isn't a builtin, it's a keyword, which means it needs to be recognized before variables get expanded, so it's not going to work even without the `exec`.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson:  _"it's not going to work even without the exec"_ was what I found also. I had to update the question, since the system wouldn't have let me added it as a comment here for some reason.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you. You should add an answer. I'd be happy to upvote you. So far I never thought about this  difference between keywords and builtins.